# Cannot locate pig-core-h1.jar. do 'ant jar', and try again

Tags: apache-pig

I have installed pig in my system by using following steps -

```
first i have downloaded pig-0.14.0.tar.gz
```

then i have extracted

```
 tar xvzf /home/impadmin/Downloads/pig-0.14.0.tar.gz
```

> sudo mv pig-0.14.0 /usr/local/pig

```
sudo chown -R hduser:hadoop pig
```

> nano ~/.bashrc

then added the following lines in bashrc file

```
# PIG binary paths
    export PIG_INSTALL="/usr/local/pig"
    export PATH="${PATH}:${PIG_INSTALL}/bin"
```

> ```
> touch ~/.pigbootup
> ```

```
 nano /usr/local/pig/conf/pig.properties
```

then added the following code in pig.properties

```
pig.logfile=/home/hduser/hadoop/pig/logs/
```

after insatllation when i am executing `pig version` command
then its giving me error -

> Cannot locate pig-core-h1.jar. do 'ant jar', and try again

there is a jar file named pig-0.14.0-core-h1.jar so i copied the same file and renamed it as pig-core-h1.jar but still its giving me the same error .
have i done anything wrong during installation?

Answer (score 1):

~/.bashrc should look like this

```
# PIG binary paths
export PIG_INSTALL="/usr/local/pig"
export PATH="$PATH:$PIG_INSTALL/bin"
```

**No need for the curly brackets**

additionally you need to (this or reboot the machine):

```
$source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: I made the correction as u mentioned but it still giving the same error.

Comment: do this: $echo $USER  <- this will give you your user name, are you: hduser or do you belong to the hadoop group?

Comment: Its hduser and with $echo $USER also its showing hduser

Comment: acho do a echo $PATH <- to make sure the path is correct, this is it ends with /usr/local/pig/bin

Comment: its showing very big path at at the end of the path its bin:/usr/local/pig/bin so i think its correct

Comment: i just downloaded: $wget http://mirror.arcor-online.net/www.apache.org/pig/pig-0.14.0/pig-0.14.0.tar.gz, extracted $tar xvzf pig-0.14.0.tar.gz , and $pig-0.14.0/bin/pig -version works: "Apache Pig version 0.14.0 (r1640057) 
compiled Nov 16 2014, 18:02:05"

Comment: can you do the basic download and run the version to check if it works?

Comment: I have again installed it and have followed the steps u mentioned but after running $pig-0.14.0/bin/pig -version its giving the same  Cannot locate pig-core-h1.jar. do 'ant jar', and try again

Comment: do you have jdk installed?
$java -version $javac -version $echo $JAVA_HOME

lets see what do you have

Comment: yes i have jdk installed
and on $java -version its showing java version "1.7.0_72"

Comment: and the others? javac and $JAVA_HOME is properly set?

Comment: I dont understand what is the problem i think these are the genuine steps required to install pig and the steps mentioned by are the basic so by that it should work

Comment: yep, the steps are very basic. I had to install pig in a virtual machine during xmas, and the only thing I installed was java 8 (in my work machine I have java 7.45).

Comment: The problem is solved now , first i thought it could be the compatibility issue so i installed another pig 0.12.1 but again with this also there was the same problem here it was showing 'ant jar-withouthadoop' so again i renamed the jar file to withouthadoop.jar but still the problem wasnt solved..then at last i restarted my system and it worked :-D  And thanks for the help :)

Comment: you should be able to run pig without hadoop (on local mode). $pig -x local

Comment: @nsu
Hey can you please tell me what is the exact location of the file that you changed.Location of file withouthadoop.jar.On extracting i am no where able to find that jar file.Please help